# WinDBG installation on server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, windbg

Is there an advantage installing WinDBG on a production server?

I have read about the difference between AdPlus and WinDBG.  Another developer said they use AdPlus on a server to create a dump file and WinDBG on their client PC to analyse it.

I understand that ADPlus is a wrapper around CDB and WinDBG is much more.  My question is: is it an overkill to install WinDBG on a production server? I am relatively new to debugging outside Visual Studio.  I am debugging a system that uses VB.NET (client application) and ASP.NET.  There is a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install WinDbg/AdPlus. If you need it you can simply xcopy the files to the server or even run the applications from a share/USB/whatever.

AdPlus is a script (well it used to be, now it is a managed application). I wouldn't call it a wrapper around CDB. It just automates using CDB for various tasks such as creating memory dumps on certain conditions. It does a good job, but you may also want to take a look at [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) as it offers some additional very useful options.

CDB, WinDbg and NTSD are all debuggers included with the Debugging Tools for Windows package. CDB and NTSD are command line tools while WinDbg offers a graphical UI (not a very fancy one but that's beside the point). They use the same debugging engine underneath.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have installed WinDBG on the server.  I have setup the filepath as per the instructions on this page: Set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH, but the symbol folder is empty.  Is there a command to actually download the symbols?

Comment: Symbols are only downloaded as needed. If you want to force loading the symbols during a debugging session you can do a `.reload /force`. Use `!sym noisy` to troubleshoot loading of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ADPlus installed you'll be able to generate dump file in case of application crash or hang or other issue (memory leak). Then you'll need to analyze this dump file. WinDBG will help you to do it. It's not neccessary to install it on production server. You can copy dump file to development machine and analyze it there. Anyway WinDBG won't be redundant. In case of critical issue you'll be able to understand the root cause ASAP.
WinDBG itself doesn't have any performance implications if it's not running.
Moreover you can use WinDBG to attach to the process and debug it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Installing WinDbg on the server would allow you to debug a live system if you are on site plus you can perform remote debugging by running WinDbg Debug service on the server which may be better if you have some unique conditions for reproduction of the error that is difficult to reproduce in your development environment.

Other than that if you are just analysing crash dumps or memory dumps then there is no advantage to installing WinDbg so it would be overkill for that reason.

There is a link here that tells you when to use AdPlus: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350

My personal thoughts are that if it does what you need then you don't need WinDbg, saying that if you had WinDbg installed you could enable gflags, take stack traces, handle traces, create dumps on specifc exceptions, dump additional information to a log that a memory dump does not contain, etc.. so essentially I would only install WinDbg if you need this, otherwise Adplus is fine.

Comment: I agree with your comment.  Is AdPlus only suitable for producing memory dumps?